# Why Angularjs bootstrap modal is not opening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ui-utils

My angularjs bootstrap modal is not opening.

```js
var app=angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $log,$modal) {
   
    $scope.user = {
        user: 'name',
        password: null,
        notes: null
    };

    $scope.open = function () {

        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', // loads the template
            backdrop: true, // setting backdrop allows us to close the modal window on clicking outside the modal window
            windowClass: 'modal', // windowClass - additional CSS class(es) to be added to a modal window template
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                $scope.user = user;
                $scope.submit = function () {
                    $log.log('Submiting user info.'); // kinda console logs this statement
                    $log.log(user); 
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); // dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
                }
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
                };
            },
            resolve: {
                user: function () {
                    return $scope.user;
                }
            }
        });//end of modal.open
    }; // end of scope.open function 
 
 
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>-->
     <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
       
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>User name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
            <label>Add some notes</label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="user.notes"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>
    </script>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I use the bootstrap version 0.6.0 the modal working fine.But If I use version 2.5.0 it gives me the error  "Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal". But I have to use version 2.5.0.How to solve the problem? Please help.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

In js part:
[plunker here.](http://embed.plnkr.co/As959V/)
**Make these two  files in separate folder, and make sure js is loaded correctly.**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.user = {
        user: 'name',
        password: null,
        notes: null
    };

    $scope.open = function () {

        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', // loads the template
            backdrop: true, // setting backdrop allows us to close the modal window on clicking outside the modal window
            windowClass: 'modal', // windowClass - additional CSS class(es) to be added to a modal window template
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                $scope.user = user;
                $scope.submit = function () {
                    $log.log('Submiting user info.'); // kinda console logs this statement
                    $log.log(user); 
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); // dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
                }
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
                };
            },
            resolve: {
                user: function () {
                    return $scope.user;
                }
            }
        });//end of modal.open
    }; // end of scope.open function
};
```

IN HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>User name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
            <label>Add some notes</label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="user.notes">

</textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>
    </script>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually I did not mean it.You are using  ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js. Using this js version in plunker as well as your code run as expected.But if you use <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script> rather than   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script> same code giving the error. I need to use the ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js

Comment: Man, check the js priority of js